# Python: Insert Dictionary into Redis

Tags: python, database, redis

I'm trying to insert a daily file containing +100,000 names into a Redis database. How can I insert a python-dictionary with a single insert with auto-increment key?

File Sample:

```
John Smith
Daniel Mason
Jessica Lee
...
```

Record Example:

```
ID: 1
Name: John Smith
Date: 2020-06-13
```

code

```
from datetime import date
import redis

# Redis config
redis_host = "localhost"
redis_port = 6379
redis_password = "secr3t"

# Today's date
today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# File
names = open("names.txt", "r")

# Redis connection
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, password=redis_password, decode_responses=True)

# Empty dictionary
names_dict = {}

for name in names:
    names_dict[name] = today

r.hmset(hkey, names_dict)
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample content of your file with expected output?

Comment: Added to the post. Very simple, each line is a name.